# OrientDB very slow with large record count

Tags: orientdb

So I am doing some testing to see if Orientdb could be the right db for an upcoming project. I created a table with four fields (which are just integers) and inserted 1,000,000 records. I am seeing extremely slow queries. My question is what is the best driver to utilize with Orient? I have tried both the python and php so far.

Comment: Hi, have you tried with an index?

Comment: How many elements are in the result? For OSyncQuery the OResultSet will contain *all* of the data in the result, potentially killing your VM when it runs out of memory. Anyone know why they didn't simply provide an iterator interface like every other DB?

Comment: @user48956 only 37 records in my result set.

Comment: Please write your query and check if it uses any indexes.